# Switch an LED on a Form by calling a variable present in another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Forms (Form1 and Form2). Form1 allows you to view the output of a camera on screen (by drawing a bitmap) that allows you to track a user if it is at a search distance from the camera. Also on Form1 draws a kind of Led which is initialized to Red, and when it draws the skeleton of the user then the Led becomes Green. (And it's fine with me)

Form2 consists of a panel and the buttons (among these there is a button which, if clicked, makes Form1 appear on the Form2 panel). Moreover, Form2 also contains a Led initialized to Red but which should become Green according to the same logic of Form1. But I can not do it. I tried to create a static public class containing a static Boolean variable that can be shared by both Forms but does not work the same.`

```
    public class Program
    {
        static public void Main()
        {
            Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate {
                Nuitrack.Release();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            };

            try
            {


                Application.Run(new Form2());
                //Application.Run(new MainForm());

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

public static class Led
{
    public static bool isGreen;
}

public class SkeletonData
    {
        protected int numJoints;
        protected ulong timestamp;

        public SkeletonData();

        public int NumUsers { get; set; }
        public Skeleton[] Skeletons { get; set; }
        public ulong Timestamp { get; }
        protected int numUsers { get; set; }
        protected Skeleton[] skeletons { get; set; }

        public Skeleton GetSkeletonByID(int id);
    }

public class Form1 : Form
{
public SkeletonData _skeletonData;
public SkeletonTracker _skeletonTracker;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnPaint(args);
         try
            {
                Nuitrack.Update(_skeletonTracker);
            }
            catch (LicenseNotAcquiredException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LicenseNotAcquired exception. Exception: ", exception);
                throw exception;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nuitrack update failed. Exception: ", exception);
            }
        // Draw a bitmap
        args.Graphics.DrawImage(_bitmap.Bitmap, new Point(0, 0));

        // Draw LED
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
        args.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 565, 403, 50, 50);

        //LED initialized to red
        args.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 565, 403, 50, 50);

        Led.isGreen = false;   

        if (_skeletonData != null)
        {
            foreach (var skeleton in _skeletonData.Skeletons)
            {
                //LED turns green                  
                args.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 565, 403, 50, 50);
                Led.isGreen = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        private bool flag;
        private bool dataon;
        private bool pause;
        private Thread t1;

        public SkeletonData _skeletonDataX;
        public SkeletonTracker _skeletonTrackerX;
        public bool semX;

        private bool isGreen;

        public FormPrincipale()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btnShow = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnDati = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnHide = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnPause = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnExit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnStart
            // 
            this.btnShow.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnShow.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 520);
            this.btnShow.Name = "btnStart";
            this.btnShow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnShow.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnShow.Text = "SHOW";
            this.btnShow.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnShow.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnShow_Click);
            //
            //btnDati
            //
            this.btnDati.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnDati.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(125, 520);
            this.btnDati.Name = "btnBitMap";
            this.btnDati.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnDati.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnDati.Text = "DATA";
            this.btnDati.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnDati.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnDati_Click);
            //
            //btnHide
            //
            this.btnHide.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(225, 520);
            this.btnHide.Name = "btnHide";
            this.btnHide.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnHide.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnHide.Text = "HIDE";
            this.btnHide.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnHide.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnHide_Click);
            //
            //btnPause
            //
            this.btnPause.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnPause.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(325, 520);
            this.btnPause.Name = "btnHide";
            this.btnPause.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnPause.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnPause.Text = "PAUSE";
            this.btnPause.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnPause.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnPause_Click);
            //
            //btnExit
            //
            this.btnExit.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnExit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(425, 520);
            this.btnExit.Name = "btnStop";
            this.btnExit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnExit.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnExit.Text = "EXIT";
            this.btnExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnExit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnExit_Click);
            //
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(650, 495);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(680, 560);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnShow);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnDati);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnHide);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnPause);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnExit);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "MyNuiTrack";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
         }

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnShow;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnDati;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnHide;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnPause;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnExit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        MainForm frm = new MainForm(); 

       // private static ManualResetEvent _mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static EventWaitHandle _mre = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: true);

        private void MyThreadMethod1()
        {
            EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
            while (flag)
            {
                frm.OttieniDati(e);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                _mre.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flag = true;
            frm.TopLevel = false;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
            frm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 6);
            frm.ControlBox = false;
            frm.Show();
            btnPause.Enabled = false; btnDati.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnDati_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadMethod1));
            t1.Start();
            dataon = true;
           _mre.Set();

            if (pause = true)
            {
                btnPause.Enabled = true; btnDati.Enabled = false;
                _mre.Set();
            }
        }

        private void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm.Visible = false;
            btnPause.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataon==true || pause==true)
            {
                if (t1.IsAlive)
                {
                    t1.Abort();
                    _mre.Close();
                }
            }
            this.Close();
            //Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnPause.Enabled = false; btnDati.Enabled = true;
            _mre.Reset();
            pause = true;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 615, 513, 40, 40);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 615, 513, 40, 40);

            if (this.isGreen)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 615, 513, 40, 40);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a logic problem where the `form1` keeps putting back the `Led.isGreen` to `false` every single time. If the `form2` refreshes at that exact moment it will see it false then update with a red ellipse. You want the logic to set it to true or false outside the paint logic. You logic seems to be if `_skeletonData ` is not null then green. Where you update that `_skeletonData` you should update the `Led.isGreen` there

Comment: I'm confused. You can post an example code that can help me

Comment: I shared a slightly different code in my question

Answer (score 1):

You can raise an event from Form1, let's call it "OnLedChanged", whenever the LED changes status. Form2 can then register to that event on Form1.

When the LED changes on Form1, Form2 will be notified and act accordingly.

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void OnLedChangedEventHandler(object sender, LedEventArgs e);

        public event OnLedChangedEventHandler OnLedChanged;

        public class LedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public bool IsGreen { get; set; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var form2 = new Form2(this);
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void ChangeLedState(bool status)
        {
            if (null != OnLedChanged) OnLedChanged(this, new LedEventArgs { IsGreen = status });
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeLedState(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Form2

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private bool isGreen;

        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            form1.OnLedChanged += (object sender, Form1.LedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                this.isGreen = e.IsGreen;
                this.Refresh();                
            };
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 10, 10, 40, 40);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, 40, 40);

            if (this.isGreen)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 10, 10, 40, 40);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form2 needs to access the instance of Form1 (in my sample I pass it in the constructor of Form2).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I understand your answer but I do not understand how to connect it to the design of the led using (e.Graphics ....)

Comment: Whenever you change the LED on Form1, raise the event by calling ChangeLedState(). That's after you change the value of Led.isGreen. Form2 will then handle the event and draw the right color on its own LED (on form2 you don't really need to override OnPaint).

Comment: @guidopastore I changed the sample and now the OnLedChange event handler on Form2 will draw your LED. You don't really need to override OnPaint in Form2.

Comment: 'MainForm.LedEventArgs' does not contain a definition of 'Graphics' and no 'Graphics' extension method has been found that accepts a first object of type 'nuitrack.MainForm.LedEventArgs'. Probably missing a directive using or a reference to an assembly.

Comment: @guidopastore I revised the sample code. I also built it on VisualStudio to make sure it works: in the event handler I set a property (isGreen) then call Refresh() which will trigger the OnPaint event. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I understand your example and I think it's right for me. There is only one problem I call Form1 from Form2 using a button (btnShow). In the main I start Form2 and clicking on the button btnShow appears Form1. Also in my forms I do not pass anything in their builders. I posted another type of example of my work can you adapt your ideas for my LED ??